# Determine program that generate network traffic

Tags: linux, networking

I have trouble. Almost every day(usually between 2 - 5 a.m.) some unknown program generate many gigabytes network traffic on linux server. How can I figure out which program is it? Maybe exist some daemon logger that can log it execution? 
                                                    **Thanks everyone)) Issue was solved.**

Comment: You can use a network traffic sniffer to dump connections to a file and examine things later. `tcpdump` works just fine. Capture maybe a minute of traffic and check later: 1. what ports are used and 2. can you make any sense of the payload transferred? Also it makes sense to dump a process list at the same time, so something like `ps aux`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install nethogs and use:

```
nethogs -t -d 100 eth0 > log.txt
```

where

-d 10 is delay of 100 seconds between each write.

-t is tracemode.

eth0 is interface name

It will mention pid and ip address and how much they recv and send.